# How to handle C# .NET POST and GET commands

Tags: c#, php, html

The current project I am working on requires a 2 way communication from the bot to my website.

Supposing the example URL is www.example.com/foobar.php or something, can you explain me how to POST and GET data from there?

Thanks a lot.

P.S. - Using webclient right?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). It's a lot easier than using WebClient, and gives you a lot more options:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://www.example.com/");

//to POST data:
var postRequest = new RestRequest("foo.php", Method.POST);
postRequest.AddParameter("name", "value");
var postResponse = client.Execute(postRequest);

//postResponse.Content will contain the raw response from the server


//To GET data
var getRequest = new RestRequest("foo.php", Method.GET);
getRequest.AddParameter("name", "value");
var getResponse = client.Execute(getRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
     NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection()
     {
         { "foo", "bar"}
     };

     byte[] responseBytes = client.UploadValues("http://www.example.com/foobar.php", nvc);
     string response = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseBytes);
}
```

Comment: So the `nvc` contains the params to look for in the URL?? and how can I parse response? Sorry. new to this stuff

Comment: The `NameValueCollection` are the parameters you want to post. My example shows how to get the response.

Comment: so the response string, whats the format of it containing the data? given the foo=1 and bar=2.. will the string be simply '12' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebClient

Look up method UploadString and DownloadString